# Sort project folders in alphabetical order in Sublime Text 3 sidebar?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

In the Sublime Text sidebar is there a way to have project folders displayed in alphabetical order, instead of by the order that the folders were added.

This is driving me nuts. I've searched everywhere for this and have given up, but it's so painful.

[image]

Comment: See my comment in Varun's answer below; I accidentally posted it there instead of here.

Answer (score 1):

The contents of side bar folders are displayed in a sorted (lexical) ordering, with all sub-folders brought to the top instead of being in their natural sort position. There is currently no setting available or internal API that allows for changing that.

That said, the ordering of top level folders that you have manually added to your project is entirely under your control and defaults (as you've noticed) to the order that they were added in.

The folders in the sidebar are listed in the order that they're listed in the `folders` section of the `sublime-project` file. You can use `Project > Edit Project` to open your project file and manually reorder the elements in the `folders` list.

Additionally you can also click and drag the top level folders to change their relative ordering. Doing so causes Sublime to automatically rewrite the project file for you.

[image: Sample of folder reordering in Sublime Text 3]

If the `Project > Edit Project` setting is not enabled, you haven't saved the current session as a project yet. In that case there will be no project file until you create one, but you can still drag to reorder the folders.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sublime plugins for this. One that I can think of is [SortTabs](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SortTabs)

Comment: Unfortunately no this only sorts folders within the main folder, not the main folder setup. I've seen this before.

Comment: Do you mean top level folders that you've added via e.g. `Project > Add Folder to Project...`? If so, you can use `Project > Edit Project` and change the order of the folders.

Comment: @OdatNurd You should probably turn your comment into an answer so that it can be accepted and made clear that it is the solution to the question.

Answer (score 0):

In Sublime Text 3, if you have "Project Manager" installed use it to CLEAR RECENT PROJECTS. Then when you look for a project to open with Ctrl-Alt-P, they will be in alphabetic order.

To install "Project Manager" on the menu go to Preferences-Package Control, then click on Install Package.  Scroll to find "Project Manager".  Click on it to install.  Restart Sublime Text.  It will be on menu at bottom of Projects.